# Modifying an array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript array

```
["200.00 K","200.50 K","300.00 K" ,"300.50 K","400.00 K","400.50 K"]
```

after parsing this array i need to get like this

```
 ["200 K","200.5 K","300 K" ,"300.5 K","400 K","400.5 K"]
```

and i'm using prototype
please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = ["200.00 K","200.50 K","300.00 K","300.50 K","400.00 K","400.50 K"];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = a[i].replace(/(?:(\.\d*[1-9])|\.)0+ /, "$1 ");
}
```

Afterwards, `a` is

```
200 K,200.5 K,300 K,300.5 K,400 K,400.5 K
```

Answer (score 4):

```
myArray = myArray.map(function (item) {
    var n = parseFloat(item);
    return n + " K";
});
```

<strike>For older browsers, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility)</strike> Actually, I think prototype does this for you automatically.

Comment: Doesn't work in older versions of some browsers like IE7/IE8 because they don't support array.map().

Comment: Good call. I've added a compatibility link.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on other answers that works in all browsers is,

```
var a = ["200.00 K","200.50 K","300.00 K" ,"300.50 K","400.00 K","400.50 K"];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  b.push(parseFloat(a[i]) + " K");
```

where `b` is the resulting array.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
for(i=0;i<arrayName.length();i++){
  arrayName[i]=parseFloat(arrayName[i])+ " K";
}
```

Comment: This isn't what they asked for.  This won't generate the requested results like "200.5 K".